# Is it possible to pass Intent "downstack" between Android activites?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, stack

If I have stack:

A->B->C

Is it possible to pass an intent back downstack to B if I do finish() on C?

(So that stack is: A->B    but B has got intent from C)

Comment: If you call startActivityForResult and call setResult just before you call finish you can pass the intent to the other activity

Comment: Nice suggestion! But then I would have to implement onActivityResult() in all my activities down in the stack (and start all my activities this way) -no? I was thinking you could receive it in like onNewIntent() or something, but maybe that is not possible?

Comment: Yes. And I don't see any other method of doing this correctly.

Comment: But your answer was really helpful! Thx!

Comment: I guess what I was looking for was passing the Intent down the stack of activities that wasn't the ones who started it. That is they were started from different tasks.

Comment: You can pass whatever intent you want to the "down activities". You can even create e new one and pass it to setResult. It's not necessarily the intent of the activities that started it.

Comment: So you mean onActivityResult() is called even for an activity that wasn't the one who initiated the startActivityForResult()?

Comment: No. That's not what I said. I said that the intent you pass to the lower activity doesn't have to be the one you passed to it on `startActivityForResult`